# Why do I not get acess to the kubernetes service depoyed on google cloud by a global url?

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dns, pulumi

> I want to access the kubernets service with the url http://staging.steinko.com/helloworld.
> I have spesified the  providing of the cluster pod, service and   in Pulumi
> The cluster looks like this

```
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes"
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi"
import * as gcp from "@pulumi/gcp"
import * as config from "./config"

const name = "gradle-ci-cd-cluster";
// Create a GKE cluster

export const cluster = new gcp.container.Cluster(name, { name: name,
    project: config.cloudProject,
    clusterAutoscaling: {enabled: true, resourceLimits:[ {resourceType: 'cpu', minimum:1 ,maximum:20 },
                                                         {resourceType: 'memory', minimum:1 ,maximum:64 }  
                                                       ]
                        },
    initialNodeCount: 1,
    nodeConfig: {
        machineType: "e2-standard-2",
        oauthScopes: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite"
        ],
    },
   location: config.cloudLocation,
 
});


// Manufacture a GKE-style kubeconfig. Note that this is slightly "different"
// because of the way GKE requires gcloud to be in the picture for cluster
// authentication (rather than using the client cert/key directly).
export const kubeconfig = pulumi.
    all([ cluster.name, cluster.endpoint, cluster.masterAuth ]).
    apply(([ name, endpoint, masterAuth ]) => {
        const context = `${config.cloudProject}_${config.cloudLocation}_${name}`;
        return `apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ${masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate}
    server: https://${endpoint}
  name: ${context}
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ${context}
    user: ${context}
  name: ${context}
current-context: ${context}
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: ${context}
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json
        cmd-path: gcloud
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
`;
    });

// Create a Kubernetes provider instance that uses our cluster from above.
export const clusterProvider = new k8s.Provider(name, {
    kubeconfig: kubeconfig,
});
```

> The Name Space, Deployment, Service Manage Zone and RecordSet looks like this

```
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import {clusterProvider} from "./Cluster"
import * as gcp from "@pulumi/gcp";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";

const name = "hello-world"
export const nameSpace =  new k8s.core.v1.Namespace('staging',{metadata: {name:'staging'}},{provider: clusterProvider})
export const nameSpaceName =  nameSpace.metadata.name;
const appLabels = { appClass: name }


export const deployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment(name, {
    metadata: { labels: appLabels,
                namespace: nameSpaceName 
              },
    spec: {
        replicas: 1,
         selector: { matchLabels: appLabels  },
        template: {
           metadata: {
                    labels: appLabels,
                },
            
            spec: { 
                         
               containers: [{ name: name,
                              image: "docker.io/steinko/gradle-ci-cd",
                               ports: [{ name: "http", containerPort: 8080 }],
                              livenessProbe:{ httpGet:{path:'/actuator/health/liveness',
                                                       port: 8080},
                                              initialDelaySeconds:5,
                                              timeoutSeconds: 1,
                                              periodSeconds: 10,
                                              failureThreshold: 3 
                                            } ,
                                readinessProbe:{ httpGet:{path:'/actuator/health/readiness',
                                                       port: 8080},
                                              initialDelaySeconds:5,
                                              timeoutSeconds: 1,
                                              periodSeconds: 10,
                                              failureThreshold: 3 
                                            } 
                            }],
            }
        }
    }
},{provider: clusterProvider});

export const deploymentName = deployment.metadata.name;

export const service = new k8s.core.v1.Service(name, 
   {
      metadata: { 
         labels: appLabels,
          namespace: nameSpaceName ,
          name:name,
          annotations: { 'external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname':'service.staging.steinko.org'}
      },
      spec: { 
               type: 'LoadBalancer',
               ports: [{port: 8080, targetPort: 8080, protocol:'TCP' } ],
               selector: appLabels,  
             } ,
         }, 
        {provider: clusterProvider} 
  ) 

export const serviceName = service.metadata.name;
export const servicePublicIP = service.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip


const zone = new gcp.dns.ManagedZone("steinko-org", {dnsName: "steinko.org.", project: 'springboot22', name:'staging-zone'});

const serviceRecordSet = new gcp.dns.RecordSet("serviceRecordSet", {
    name: "staging.steinko.org.",
    type: "A",
    ttl: 300,
    project: 'springboot22',
    managedZone: zone.name,
     rrdatas: [servicePublicIP],
});
```

> When running  pulumi up  gives following report

```
steinko@Steins-MacBook-Pro infAsCode % pulumi up
Previewing update (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/steinko/Gradle-Ci-CD/dev/previews/c8ae9e31-a1c1-4d77-9f47-bb00ba136c51

     Type                              Name                  Plan       
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack               Gradle-Ci-CD-dev      create     
 +   ├─ gcp:dns:ManagedZone            steinko-org           create     
 +   ├─ gcp:container:Cluster          gradle-ci-cd-cluster  create     
 +   ├─ pulumi:providers:kubernetes    gradle-ci-cd-cluster  create     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Namespace   staging               create     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Service     hello-world           create     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:apps/v1:Deployment  hello-world           create     
 +   └─ gcp:dns:RecordSet              serviceRecordSet      create     
 
Resources:
    + 8 to create

Do you want to perform this update? yes
Updating (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/steinko/Gradle-Ci-CD/dev/updates/37

     Type                              Name                  Status      
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack               Gradle-Ci-CD-dev      created     
 +   ├─ gcp:dns:ManagedZone            steinko-org           created     
 +   ├─ gcp:container:Cluster          gradle-ci-cd-cluster  created     
 +   ├─ pulumi:providers:kubernetes    gradle-ci-cd-cluster  created     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Namespace   staging               created     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:core/v1:Service     hello-world           created     
 +   ├─ kubernetes:apps/v1:Deployment  hello-world           created     
 +   └─ gcp:dns:RecordSet              serviceRecordSet      created     
 
Outputs:
    deployment     : {
        apiVersion: "apps/v1"
        id        : "staging/hello-world-6l7hw292"
        kind      : "Deployment"
        metadata  : {
            annotations      : {
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision               : "1"
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"Deployment\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"pulumi.com/autonamed\":\"true\"},\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"pulumi\",\"appClass\":\"hello-world\"},\"name\":\"hello-world-6l7hw292\",\"namespace\":\"staging\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":1,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"appClass\":\"hello-world\"}},\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"appClass\":\"hello-world\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"docker.io/steinko/gradle-ci-cd\",\"livenessProbe\":{\"failureThreshold\":3,\"httpGet\":{\"path\":\"/actuator/health/liveness\",\"port\":8080},\"initialDelaySeconds\":5,\"periodSeconds\":10,\"timeoutSeconds\":1},\"name\":\"hello-world\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":8080,\"name\":\"http\"}],\"readinessProbe\":{\"failureThreshold\":3,\"httpGet\":{\"path\":\"/actuator/health/readiness\",\"port\":8080},\"initialDelaySeconds\":5,\"periodSeconds\":10,\"timeoutSeconds\":1}}]}}}}\n"
                pulumi.com/autonamed                            : "true"
            }
            creationTimestamp: "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
            generation       : 1
            labels           : {
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
                appClass                    : "hello-world"
            }
            managedFields    : [
                [0]: {
                    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
                    fieldsType: "FieldsV1"
                    fieldsV1  : {
                        f:metadata: {
                            f:annotations: {
                            }
                            f:labels     : {
                            }
                        }
                        f:spec    : {
                            f:selector               : {
                                f:matchLabels: {
                                }
                            }
                            f:strategy               : {
                                f:rollingUpdate: {
                                }
                            }
                            f:template               : {
                                f:metadata: {
                                    f:labels: {
                                    }
                                }
                                f:spec    : {
                                    f:containers                   : {
                                        k:{"name":"hello-world"}: {
                                            f:livenessProbe           : {
                                                f:httpGet            : {
                                                }
                                            }
                                            f:ports                   : {
                                                k:{"containerPort":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}: {
                                                }
                                            }
                                            f:readinessProbe          : {
                                                f:httpGet            : {
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    manager   : "pulumi-resource-kubernetes"
                    operation : "Update"
                    time      : "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
                }
                [1]: {
                    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
                    fieldsType: "FieldsV1"
                    fieldsV1  : {
                        f:metadata: {
                            f:annotations: {
                            }
                        }
                        f:status  : {
                            f:conditions        : {
                                k:{"type":"Available"}  : {
                                }
                                k:{"type":"Progressing"}: {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    manager   : "kube-controller-manager"
                    operation : "Update"
                    time      : "2021-05-19T07:39:53Z"
                }
            ]
            name             : "hello-world-6l7hw292"
            namespace        : "staging"
            resourceVersion  : "1349"
            selfLink         : "/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/staging/deployments/hello-world-6l7hw292"
            uid              : "300e8e9b-8385-4d90-9913-8eb12fe18183"
        }
        spec      : {
            progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
            replicas               : 1
            revisionHistoryLimit   : 10
            selector               : {
                matchLabels: {
                    appClass: "hello-world"
                }
            }
            strategy               : {
                rollingUpdate: {
                    maxSurge      : "25%"
                    maxUnavailable: "25%"
                }
                type         : "RollingUpdate"
            }
            template               : {
                metadata: {
                    labels: {
                        appClass: "hello-world"
                    }
                }
                spec    : {
                    containers                   : [
                        [0]: {
                            image                   : "docker.io/steinko/gradle-ci-cd"
                            imagePullPolicy         : "Always"
                            livenessProbe           : {
                                failureThreshold   : 3
                                httpGet            : {
                                    path  : "/actuator/health/liveness"
                                    port  : 8080
                                    scheme: "HTTP"
                                }
                                initialDelaySeconds: 5
                                periodSeconds      : 10
                                successThreshold   : 1
                                timeoutSeconds     : 1
                            }
                            name                    : "hello-world"
                            ports                   : [
                                [0]: {
                                    containerPort: 8080
                                    name         : "http"
                                    protocol     : "TCP"
                                }
                            ]
                            readinessProbe          : {
                                failureThreshold   : 3
                                httpGet            : {
                                    path  : "/actuator/health/readiness"
                                    port  : 8080
                                    scheme: "HTTP"
                                }
                                initialDelaySeconds: 5
                                periodSeconds      : 10
                                successThreshold   : 1
                                timeoutSeconds     : 1
                            }
                            terminationMessagePath  : "/dev/termination-log"
                            terminationMessagePolicy: "File"
                        }
                    ]
                    dnsPolicy                    : "ClusterFirst"
                    restartPolicy                : "Always"
                    schedulerName                : "default-scheduler"
                    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
                }
            }
        }
        status    : {
            availableReplicas : 1
            conditions        : [
                [0]: {
                    lastTransitionTime: "2021-05-19T07:39:53Z"
                    lastUpdateTime    : "2021-05-19T07:39:53Z"
                    message           : "Deployment has minimum availability."
                    reason            : "MinimumReplicasAvailable"
                    status            : "True"
                    type              : "Available"
                }
                [1]: {
                    lastTransitionTime: "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
                    lastUpdateTime    : "2021-05-19T07:39:53Z"
                    message           : "ReplicaSet \"hello-world-6l7hw292-68f4b89dcf\" has successfully progressed."
                    reason            : "NewReplicaSetAvailable"
                    status            : "True"
                    type              : "Progressing"
                }
            ]
            observedGeneration: 1
            readyReplicas     : 1
            replicas          : 1
            updatedReplicas   : 1
        }
        urn       : "urn:pulumi:dev::Gradle-Ci-CD::kubernetes:apps/v1:Deployment::hello-world"
    }
    deploymentName : "hello-world-6l7hw292"
    nameSpace      : {
        apiVersion: "v1"
        id        : "staging"
        kind      : "Namespace"
        metadata  : {
            annotations      : {
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Namespace\",\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"pulumi\"},\"name\":\"staging\"}}\n"
            }
            creationTimestamp: "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
            labels           : {
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
            }
            managedFields    : [
                [0]: {
                    apiVersion: "v1"
                    fieldsType: "FieldsV1"
                    fieldsV1  : {
                        f:metadata: {
                            f:annotations: {
                            }
                            f:labels     : {
                            }
                        }
                        f:status  : {
                        }
                    }
                    manager   : "pulumi-resource-kubernetes"
                    operation : "Update"
                    time      : "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
                }
            ]
            name             : "staging"
            resourceVersion  : "779"
            selfLink         : "/api/v1/namespaces/staging"
            uid              : "a722d333-2a86-4e96-9ce1-6ded3a84a64c"
        }
        spec      : {
            finalizers: [
                [0]: "kubernetes"
            ]
        }
        status    : {
            phase: "Active"
        }
        urn       : "urn:pulumi:dev::Gradle-Ci-CD::kubernetes:core/v1:Namespace::staging"
    }
    nameSpaceName  : "staging"
    service        : {
        apiVersion: "v1"
        id        : "staging/hello-world"
        kind      : "Service"
        metadata  : {
            annotations      : {
                external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname       : "service.staging.steinko.org"
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Service\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname\":\"service.staging.steinko.org\"},\"labels\":{\"app.kubernetes.io/managed-by\":\"pulumi\",\"appClass\":\"hello-world\"},\"name\":\"hello-world\",\"namespace\":\"staging\"},\"spec\":{\"ports\":[{\"port\":8080,\"protocol\":\"TCP\",\"targetPort\":8080}],\"selector\":{\"appClass\":\"hello-world\"},\"type\":\"LoadBalancer\"}}\n"
            }
            creationTimestamp: "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
            finalizers       : [
                [0]: "service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup"
            ]
            labels           : {
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "pulumi"
                appClass                    : "hello-world"
            }
            managedFields    : [
                [0]: {
                    apiVersion: "v1"
                    fieldsType: "FieldsV1"
                    fieldsV1  : {
                        f:metadata: {
                            f:annotations: {
                            }
                            f:labels     : {
                            }
                        }
                        f:spec    : {
                            f:ports                : {
                                k:{"port":8080,"protocol":"TCP"}: {
                                }
                            }
                            f:selector             : {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    manager   : "pulumi-resource-kubernetes"
                    operation : "Update"
                    time      : "2021-05-19T07:38:52Z"
                }
                [1]: {
                    apiVersion: "v1"
                    fieldsType: "FieldsV1"
                    fieldsV1  : {
                        f:metadata: {
                            f:finalizers: {
                            }
                        }
                        f:status  : {
                            f:loadBalancer: {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    manager   : "kube-controller-manager"
                    operation : "Update"
                    time      : "2021-05-19T07:39:39Z"
                }
            ]
            name             : "hello-world"
            namespace        : "staging"
            resourceVersion  : "1167"
            selfLink         : "/api/v1/namespaces/staging/services/hello-world"
            uid              : "124042c4-b8db-4962-ad00-996dc34e1903"
        }
        spec      : {
            clusterIP            : "10.43.248.226"
            externalTrafficPolicy: "Cluster"
            ports                : [
                [0]: {
                    nodePort  : 31864
                    port      : 8080
                    protocol  : "TCP"
                    targetPort: 8080
                }
            ]
            selector             : {
                appClass: "hello-world"
            }
            sessionAffinity      : "None"
            type                 : "LoadBalancer"
        }
        status    : {
            loadBalancer: {
                ingress: [
                    [0]: {
                        ip: "35.228.10.250"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        urn       : "urn:pulumi:dev::Gradle-Ci-CD::kubernetes:core/v1:Service::hello-world"
    }
    serviceName    : "hello-world"
    servicePublicIP: "35.228.10.250"

Resources:
    + 8 created

Duration: 3m37s
```

> When I try to browse http://35.228.10.250/helloworld i get the message
> This site can’t be reached35.228.10.250 took too long to respond.
> Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

> When I try the http://staging.steinko.com/helloworld I get the message
> This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in staging.steinko.com.
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

> What must I do to get access to the service in a global url?

Comment: Can you try this command `curl -H "host:  staging.steinko.com" http://35.228.10.250/helloworld` and let me know if it works?

Comment: I run the command above. The result was: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.228.10.250 port 80: Operation timed out

Comment: your service's `port` should be 80, but it's configured as 8080 (keep targetPort as 8080)

Comment: When I change the port to 80  Is curl -H "host:  staging.steinko.com" http://35.228.10.250/helloworld 
Hello World%       And http://35.228.10.250/helloworld  in the browser return Hello World. But http://staging.steinko.com/helloworld still deliver This site can't be reach . What must I fix?

Comment: The A record you have is for `staging.steinko.org`, not `staging.steinko.com`. But you probably just made a typo in your comment. Are the other RecordSets in that managed zone working?

Comment: have you checked your worker nodes to ensure the worker-node is listening?  (e.g. netstat -ntlp and look for the tcp port of your exposed app).  If it's not listed then your K8s service isn't configured or configured correctly.  If it is and you can hop into your container and verify it's listener as well, then you likely have a firewall issue on the worker or some kind of public exposure limitation from Google Cloud you'll have to resolve -- I'm not familiar with gcloud.